# how to change jqgrid paging style

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, custom-paging, jqgrid-formatter

I want to change default pagination of jqgrid. I want the pagination as given below

**1 2 3 4 5.. Next**

Is it supported by default? How can i achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800400/add-numeric-pager-to-jqgrid/5835542#5835542). Is it what you want?

Comment: exact dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800400/add-numeric-pager-to-jqgrid?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the wiki it says you can create your own custom pager, you might take a look at this -> http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager

Comment: Well sound like its not flexible enough to customize it...Did anybody do that?

Comment: Did you read the article? below theres an sections about customization, you customize the whole pager just how you want it.

Comment: I read it but it doesnt address the thing i am looking for. You can only set the default paging text etc.

Comment: you mean the urls or what? You can configure the pager completly with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do exactly same thing you want. 
sad to tell, the structure is hard coded. you have to rewrite the `setPager()` function by modifying the jqgrid source code. I mean it can't be down by overwrite some function.