# JQGRID Custom pager like Google

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid

I've just started using the JQGRID componant which is excellent.

My problem is with the pager which is awful and looks like something out of a 1990's windows desktop app.

Does anyone know of how to implement a pager that mimics the style of Google?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe more clear what you want? How you define the "Google" style? If you mean the pager with the text "About 333,000,000 results" above and "numbers 1 2 3 ... Next" at the end of the page, than it's designed for the case when you **don't know exactly the number of items in the grid**. Another disadvantage of such pager is that it's large enough. If you have some grids and another information on the page it's really disadvantage. I recommend you additionally to look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835542/315935) if you don't seen it before.