# jqgrid Custom Numeric Pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

How to change jqgrid pagination 
like: ***Pages 1 of 15 (150 Items) << < 1 2 3 4 5.. 12 13 15 > >>***

Both display in center td.

Comment: Your question is not clear ..

Comment: I want to customize the layout of pagination in footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835542/315935) which provides the corresponding demos. In general you can create the pager in any other custom way. You cab . It's important just to place links with `1 2 3 4 5 ... 12 13 15` and bind click event handler for the links. Inside of the event handler you need just trigger `reloadGrid` event on the grid with the corresponding `page` parameter: `$("#gridid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: newPage}]);`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) additionally.

**UPDATED**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835542/315935) is 3.5 years old. The demos use jqGrid 3.8.2 version. Starting with version 4.3.2 (the current is 4.6) jqGrid supports jQuery events. It allows easy to register more as one event handler. Disadvantage of classical callbacks like `loadComplete` or `onSelectRow`: "there can be only one". You can't define one *common* callback `loadComplete` with initialization of pager for example and to use another *additional* callback `loadComplete` with *specific* additional actions. You can define common `loadComplete` by

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

but it will be **overwritten** if one define `loadComplete` in the grid. On the other side one can register **multiple** `jqGridLoadComplete` or jqGridAfterLoadComplete event handlers and all from there will be called. jQuery *appends* the list of event handlers instead of overwriting it.

So to implement new feature, like new pager, in a complex project which contains many many grids I can suggest you two snippets.

The first one required *small* modification of the code. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithLinkPager2.htm). Grid options don't contains any `loadComplete` callback, but includes the line

```js
$grid.on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", refreshPager);
```

*before* creating the grid `$grid`. The code of `refreshPager` is the modified copy of `loadComplete` callback from the old demo. In the way *multiple* `"jqGridAfterLoadComplete"` event handler can be registered.

You can modify the code by including the line

```js
myjqGridInit($grid);
```

before every grid creating and place the code of `myjqGridInit` function in separate `.js` file which you includes after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. In the way you can place all common project initialization of jqGrid (like registering of `$grid.on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", refreshPager);`) in one place of your project. It will be easy to maintain such project.

If you don't use `onInitGrid` callback till now I can suggest you the second alternative which allows you minimal changes of the existing pages with jqGrid. If you use master pages in your project you could need just include the following code *after* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and before any grid is created:

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
    onInitGrid: function () {
        refreshPager.call(this);
    }
});
```

The above code defines default `onInitGrid` callback which makes all project initialization. The code of `refreshPager` you can of case place in separate `.js` file too and just include it on the master page.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithLinkPager2_.htm) demonstrates the snippet. In the way you could implement new feature in *all* jqGrids of your existing projects with minimal modification of the code. The only restriction: you should don't use `onInitGrid` callback in your grids, because it will *overwrite* the common initialization.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, Can you please explain your previous answered post in more detail, or is there any way to do this work in (jquery.jqGrid.min.js)? I have done other things just numeric part (1 2 3 4 5 ... 12 13 15) is left now and I have using 70 JQGrid in project its difficult to find or edit loadComplete: function().

Comment: @user3650273: You are welcome! See **UPDATED** part of my answer.