# jqGrid Custom Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Using jqGrid how to customize the pagination. Please find the below screenshot.

Any one place help me how to achieve this functionality using jqGrid.
[image]

Comment: Do you need jQGrid  only or any JS framework will work, you can try [datatables](https://datatables.net/) which is much easier then jQGrid

Comment: JQGrid only existing one i need to modify

Comment: Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972674/jqgrid-custom-numeric-pagination) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800400/add-numeric-pager-to-jqgrid/5835542#5835542) might help. There is also a [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithLinkPager2.htm) similar to your requirement.

Comment: How to add current page in that demo mentioned above one. If you have any idea please help me.